# AsyncTask with SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm a beginner in android. I want to perform basic CRUD operations of SQLiteDatabase using AsyncTask class. I have one int and 4 String parameters for table.How do i pass arguments to insert data in table from DataBaseHelper Class to AsyncTask Class.

Comment: You should use [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), not `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) tutorial explains the usage of `ContentProvider` and `Loader`. Although Content Providers are overkill for small applications, it is the best way to implement a `SQLiteDatabase` within your application. Basically it allows you to have a app database accessible from every other application you wish and eases the usage of CRUD operations inside any of those.

With it, you don't need any reference to your SQLiteOpenHelper in order to make any operation in your database. Content Providers work by calling `getContentResolver().<insert/delete/update>()` directly in your `Activity`, keeping your code clean. Also, every operation you do using this API is sent to the background thread, leaving you no work at all besides configuring it for the first time.

A class that extends `ContentProvider`will have 4 methods: `insert()`, `delete()`, `update()` and `query()`. These same methods must receive an `URI` that points to the table you will be using in that operation. Cool, huh? 4 methods for **every** operation in **any** table. You could also use [a Constants class](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=2) to map your URIs and boom: you got state of the art code.

[image: contentprovider example]

Comment: Thanks a lot.... I will try it.... if you have any reference link for AsyncTask Activity also then please share....